# me podrian ayudar en un programa de java

Tags: java

me dejaron Calcular la suma de los N elementos de dos arreglos(A, B) y que la suma se muestre en otro arreglo (C)
a penas estoy viendo esto y con la pandemia las clases en linea no las comprendo muy bien
me ayudarian por favor

Comment: Porfavor lee [ask], debes incluir tu codigo para que nosotros podamos ayudarte, el sitio no resuelve tareas, responde a dudas concretas de un codigo que tengas y nos muestres.

Answer (score 0):

Dos vectores se suman elemento a elemento, y el resultado lo puedes guardar en la variable o estructura que más te convenga, que puede ser, como este caso, otro vector.

Como repaso rápido a los vectores, podemos declarar un vector e iniciarlo a una instancia de un tamaño determinado.

```
int[] vector;    // Declaración de un vector (no existe, solo declaramos la variable)
vector = new int[10];    // Creación de un vector de tamaño 10
```

Este vector tendría 10 elementos, indizados de 0 a 9, e inicialmente todos estarán a 0.

Para leer o escribir valores en el vector, podemos acceder a sus elementos escribiendo el nombre de la variable, indicando el índice del elemento al que queremos acceder entre corchetes.

```
vector[0] = 10;    // Metemos el número 10 en la primera posición del vector, con índice 0
vector[9] = 19;    // Asignamos ahora el número 19 a la última posición del vector
```

Si los vectores son del mismo tamaño (mismo número de elementos), entonces todo lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer ambos vectores, sumando los elementos con igual índice, y guardándolos en las posiciones correspondientes del vector resultado.

```
int elementos = 10;
int[] vectorA = new int[elementos];
int[] vectorB = new int[elementos];
// ... Rellenamos los vectores con enteros
int[] resultado = new int[elementos];
for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
    resultado[i] = vectorA[i] + vectorB[i];
}
```

Recuerda además que `vector.length` nos devuelve el número de elementos del vector, es decir, el número con el que hicimos la llamada a `new`, que en este caso es 10.